# Confused with homebrew version mysql and official mysql preferences pane on mac

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I downloaded mysql for my Mac from official website 'mysql.com', then launched it on my server using preferences pane and as well as from command line using

`sudo /usr/local/etc/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Its working good, but during my development process i want to change the sql_mode,because i am getting below error

> sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Many of them said to change sql mode config in `/usr/mysql/my.cnf`, but unfortunately i don't see that directory on my mac, So i installed Homebrew version mysql ,this also not working.

My Problem is where I can find **my.cnf** file on my mac? now i am not using homebrew version of mysql, I'm using official mysql downloaded from mysql.com/downloads.

Comment: Normally `/etc/my.cnf` for Homebrew, though sometimes `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`. If you're ever confused: `find / -name my.cnf` will find it.

Comment: now i am not using homebrew, where i found this file for official mysql server method?

Comment: `find` will find it. What did it dig up?

Comment: mysql for mac downloaded from mysql.com, not homebrew version

Comment: @tadman where i want to run this find command? in terminal?

Comment: With the Terminal will be the easiest way.

Comment: This belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution, i created new file inside /etc called my.cnf and set this as

```
[mysqld]
# Default : STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_mode = ""
```

Now its working great :) Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Run `mysql --help` it will show you the config file that is being loaded.

Comment: it shows me : Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf .   but i cant find in directory

Comment: Are you sure none of  the files exist?  Try "cat /etc/my.cnf " or "cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf" or "cat /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf"